# Splitting Multiple Columns,Rows with Different Delimiters

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is SQL Table(UserTable)

```
    ROWNO|                CODE                        |CODEID
    -----+--------------------------------------------+-------------+
    1     ABD~Monthly~1~2~3~4~5!INDIA~Weekly~1~2~2~3~1  19
    2     CED~Weekly~1~3~3~4~5!SA~Weekly~4~2~2~3~5      20
```

The Code Column Contains Complex Statement with Lots of delimiters

The Delimiter ~ denotes Column and ! denoted Row

I have to bring it back as a result like this

```
        CODE1| CODE2 |CODE3|CODE4|CODE5|CODE6|CODE7|CODEID
        -----+-------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+------+
        ABD   Monthly  1      2     3      4   5       19
        INDIA Weekly   1      2     2      3   1       19
        CED   Weekly   1      3     3      4   5       20
        SA    Weekly   4      2     2      3   5       20
```

Please Somebody help me here to get the query !

Thanks in advance , Jayendran

Comment: What is your database?

Comment: The table resides in userdb with in a SQL server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an Inline approach (no udfs)

Use `OUTER APPLY` to show NULL values

**Example**

```
Select C.*
      ,A.CODEID
 From YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
                      ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
                From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(A.[CODE],'!','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
                Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
             ) B
 Cross Apply (
                Select Code1 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[1]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Code2 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[2]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Code3 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[3]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Code4 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[4]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Code5 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[5]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Code6 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[6]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Code7 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[7]','varchar(max)')))
                From  (Select Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(B.RetVal,'~','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml) as xDim) as A 
             ) C
```

**Returns**

[image]

**[dbFiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=cf06011560d24d3226aa7316ab64d376)**

Comment: May i know what is the purpose of '§§Split§§' in the Code ?  Also how can i use this symbol '§' in my Keyboard It seems totally different !

Comment: @JayendranRosh The §§Split§§ is used to ensure XML safe and truly uniquie parsing and to get this via the keyboard, while holding down the ALT key type 0167 and release

Answer (score 0):

First you should really consider to change your datamodel, but that's on another paper :).

I don't know which database you are using, but you you can try the XML-way.

You can combine these answers:

For creating the rows
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16083088/4132760

For createing the columns
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15108499/4132760

If you are using SQl 2016 you can rely on the new split function
https://stackoverflow.com/a/36305493/4132760

If you can provide your used databse system i'm sure somebody can give you a complete solution.